# Concourse 5.0 Installation in AWS

Tags: concourse

We have been trying to setup `concourse 5.0.0` (we already set up `4.2.2`) in our AWS. We have created two instances one is for web and another is for worker. We are able to see the site up and running but we are not able to run our pipeline. we checked the logs and noticed that worker throwing the below error.

```
Workerr.beacon.forward-conn.failed-to-dial","data":{"addr":"127.0.0.1:7777","error":"dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7777: connect: connection refused","network":"tcp","session":"9.1.4"}}
```

We are assuming worker is struggling to connect to `web` instance and wondering if this could be due to missing gdn configuration. Concourse `5.0.0` release included both concourse and gdn binaries. we want to try `--garden-config` file to see if that fixes the problem.

can somebody suggest how do we write garden config file ?

Comment: I don't have any garden config in my concourse deployment (deployed by bosh). However, did you set the worker_gateway on the web vm, properly?
```      worker_gateway:
        authorized_keys:
          - ((worker_key.public_key))
        host_key: ((tsa_host_key))
      token_signing_key: ((token_signing_key))```

Comment: Hi @muehsi, we figured it out , it was the issue with gdn(garden binary) which was  not configured. we had to include `CONCOURSE_BIND_IP=xx.xx.x.x` ( IP where your `gdn` is located) and `CONCOURSE_BIND_PORT=7777`( `gdn's` port) in wroker.env file. Thanks for the response !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @umamaheswararao-meka. Your solution allowed me to complete the installation. Please add your response as an answer so other people can find it easily

Comment: Thank you @alfredocambera, Sure I will add my response as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and solved it using @umamaheswararao-meka's answer. (Using ubuntu 18.04 on EC2)

Also had a problem with containers not being able to resolve domain names (https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/2187). Here is the error message:

```
resource script '/opt/resource/check []' failed: exit status 1

stderr:
failed to ping registry: 2 error(s) occurred:

* ping https: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
* ping http: Get http://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf -y

# These are cloudflare's DNS servers
sudo echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
sudo echo "nameserver 1.0.0.1" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
sudo resolvconf -u

cat /etc/resolv.conf # just to make sure changes are in place
# restart concourse service
```

Containers make use of resolv.conf and as the file is generated dynamically on ubuntu 18.04 this was the easiest way of making containers inherit this configuration.

---

Also relevant snippets from `man resolvconf`

```
   -u     Just run the update scripts (if updating is enabled).

   /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail
          File to be appended to the dynamically generated resolver configuration file.  To append
          nothing,  make  this an empty file.  This file is a good place to put a resolver options
          line if one is needed, e.g.,
```

Comment: @FiftiN disabling the default DNS server on EC2 may affect services installed on your box as this DNS server may resolve names for other boxes on your AWS account. This is why I prefer to add a DNS server instead of replacing current config

Comment: How to do it? I didn't find working solution except the above.

Comment: My provided solutions adds DNS servers to the dynamic configuration file by updating `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see :) Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Please upvote my answer if it solves your problem

Comment: This worked for me (except that I used `8.8.8.8` as the nameserver) on Ubuntu 18.04 with Concourse v. 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

it was the issue with `gdn`(garden binary) which was not configured. we had to include `CONCOURSE_BIND_IP=xx.xx.x.x` ( IP where your `gdn` is located) and `CONCOURSE_BIND_PORT=7777`( `gdn's` port) in `wroker.env` file. Which solved the problem for us.